# Profile dropdown unreadable on beta sites

Tags: bug, status-completed

On beta sites the text in the profile drop down box is very light blue on a white background. So it is extremely hard to read it.

Comment: having a look...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed in code; will be deploying soon